# Can i mine with a GTX 760?

Tags: mining-profitability, mining-hardware, gpu, amd

Well, bit coin mining is looking more and more promising and to be honest, i don't know a lot. I heard you get a lot from AMD cards, but if i use my Nvidia card will it even be worth it? Thanks in advance!

Also, is there a guide to start mining? like a beginners guide for retards?

edit: By worth it i mean will my power bill be more than what im earning, or have they come up so much that its not a big deal?

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely mine with that card. My recommendation is you look up cudaminer. With the same card as you I get about 140 khash/s mining litecoins (using scrypt). I don't remember which instructions I used to set it up.